# Regex : split on '.' but not in substrings like "J.K. Rowling"

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for names of books and authors in a bunch of texts, like:

```
my_text = """
    My favorites books of all time are:
    Harry potter by J. K. Rowling, Dune (first book) by Frank Herbert;
    and Le Petit Prince by Antoine de Saint Exupery (I read it many times). That's it by the way.
"""
```

Right now I am using the following code to split the text on separators like this:

```
pattern = r" *(.+) by ((?: ?\w+)+)"

matches = re.findall(pattern, my_text)

res = []
for match in matches:
    res.append((match[0], match[1]))

print(res) # [('Harry potter', 'J'), ('K. Rowling, Dune (first book)', 'Frank Herbert'), ('and Le Petit Prince', 'Antoine de Saint Exupery '), ("I read it many times). That's it", 'the way')]
```

Even if there are false positive (like 'that's it by the way') my main problem is with authors that are cut when written as initials, which is pretty common.

I can't figure out how to allow initials like "J. K. Rowling" (or the same without space before / after dot like "J.K.Rowling")

Comment: Please include examples of some '.' instances where you do want to have a split in your example text. How do you propose to identify '.' that cause splits vs '.' that are parts of names? Do you want to choose '.' with two or more letters preceding it. Or '.' with non-capitalized letters preceding them, or what? Do you also want to split on other sentence-ending punctuation like '?' and '!'?

Comment: You could try a regex string like `r" *(.+) by ((?: ?(?:\w\.|\w+))+)"`

Comment: I get a [different output](https://ideone.com/YApxKF), so what is the regex you are using?

Comment: You are right, I am using the provided regex but screwed up on the reproducible example, sorry

Comment: With your current samples something like [`by\s+([A-Z]\w*(?:[.\s]+\w+)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/UQNFkb/1) could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change pattern to the following

```py
pattern = r" *(.+) by ((?: ?[A-Z].?)+ ?(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+)"
```

To allow for initials in the author's name, we need to make some modifications to the pattern. First, we will add an optional dot after the initial, using the character class "[A-Z]", which matches any upper case letter, followed by a "." (dot) and "?" (question mark) to make it optional. Next, we will add an optional space " ?" after the dot. Next, we will repeat the pattern for multiple initials using "+".

when I tried your code I with my pattern I got:

```bash
('Harry potter', 'J. K. Rowling')
```

It seems to ignore the rest of the authors but it works for authors with initials. let me know if you want me to figure out how to make it work with both initials and non-initials if that make any sense.

Here I solve the problem, it took a while:

```py
import re

pattern = r" *(?:and )?(.+?) by ([A-Z](?:\.|\w)+(?: [A-Z](?:\.|\w)+)*)"
matches = re.finditer(pattern, my_text)

result = []
for match in matches:
    book_title = match.group(1)
    author = match.group(2)
    result.append((book_title, author))

print(result)
```

which will give:

```bash
[('Harry potter', 'J. K. Rowling'), (', Dune (first book)', 'Frank Herbert'), ('Le Petit Prince', 'Antoine')]
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you, yes please because I cant figure it out

Comment: I think it is solved, let me know if it works.

Comment: Hello, it does not work quite completely, so I ended up keeping my previous regex, and adding a re.sub() just before on my text to remove dots preceded by Capital letters